# Trying to change variable to javaScript using "for (element in window)": why does it return undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, window, undefined

So I'm trying to program a button object for **html canvas shenanigans**. Here is my code, which I will explain after:

```
gameFont = "Calibri";                       // Default button font
fontSize = 12;                          // Default button font size in px
fontColour = "white";                   // Default button font colour

function ui_button(options) {
    var that = {};

    that.context = options.context;
    that.hpos = options.hpos;
    that.vpos = options.vpos;
    that.width = options.width;
    that.height = options.height;
    that.radius = options.radius;
    that.txt = options.txt;
    that.fontColour = options.fontColour;
    that.fontSize = options.fontSize;
    that.font = options.font;

    // Check if any of our keys weren't specified. 
    for (i=0;i<Object.keys(that).length;i++) {
        // If the value is empty
        if (!Object.values(that)[i]) {
            // Then search the ENTIRE window for variables
            for (element in window) {
                // If the current element shares a name with the key we tested
                if (element == Object.keys(that)[i]) {
                    // Replace this object's value with the global one
                    alert("Changing "+Object.keys(that)[i]+" with value of "+Object.values(that)[i]+" into "+eval(element));
                    alert(eval(element));
                    var ttt = eval(element)[0];
                    alert("ttt:"+ttt);
                    Object.values(that)[i] = ttt;
                    alert(Object.values(that)[i]);
                    alert("Internal var "+Object.keys(that)[i]+" now has value of "+Object.values(that)[i]+" from "+eval(element));
                }
            }               
        }
    }

/* blahblah, more function stuff for the object */

return that
}
```

Then, I'm producing one of these objects with the following definitions:

```
but_endTurn = ui_button({
    context: ctx,
    hpos: 50,
    vpos: 50,
    width: 80,
    height: 30,
    radius: 5,
    txt: "End Turn"
});
```

When I do this, the function does the same process for all undefined variables: let's use `fontColour` as an example here.

When it realises that `fontColour` is undefined, it scours elements in window for a variable named fontColour.

It finds it.

```
alert(eval(element));
```

This correctly gives me a value of `"white"`.

Next, I make a variable out of it:

```
var ttt = eval(element)[0];
alert("ttt:"+ttt);
```

This also correctly states `"white"` in the debug alert.

Good so far. Then I define a variable as `ttt` (same thing happens when I define it straight as eval(element)[0])

```
                Object.values(that)[i] = ttt;
                alert(Object.values(that)[i]);
                alert("Internal var "+Object.keys(that)[i]+" now has value of "+Object.values(that)[i]+" from "+eval(element));
```

But the alert **ALWAYS** returns `"undefined"` for `Object.values(that)[i]`! Even though the other variables in the second alert always show up correctly.

Can anybody help me figure out why this is and/or offer a solution?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns `undefined`, because [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns a newly created array containing all values of `that` and not references to the original object properties. So all you do is wrting the content of `ttt` to a temporary array.

Possible solution:

```
that[Object.keys(that)[i]] = window[element];
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jYWOOj

---

However I would not iterate over the window object nor would I use eval. What stops you from using another global object which contains all default settings, like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeGPrb

---

If you really want to define your global variables separately at the window object I would recommend iterating over your keys like this:

```
for (let element in that) {
  if (typeof that[element] === 'undefined' && window[element]) {
    that[element] = window[element];
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zprYBo

Comment: I modified my code exactly as you suggested, removing eval and storing my global values in an object while I was at it. It fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your help.